# Eigen matrix-free BiCGSTAB error: "THIS_EXPRESSION_IS_NOT_A_LVALUE__IT_IS_READ_ONLY"

Tags: c++, eigen

For a personal hobby project I want to solve for a big (~100k by ~100k entries) dense float matrix (say "A") the equation A*x = y for x given a known y (~100k entries). I would like to use the BiCGSTAB algorithm for this. As I have already used the Eigen library in the project, I wanted to use the implementation provided by the Eigen library. My computer memory does not allow me to store the complete matrix "A" in memory, so I have to find a workaround. Eigen provides the option to use matrix-free solvers:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html

I have tried to implement a similar matrix wrapper for the BiCGSTAB algorithm. My idea is to only calculate entries of the matrix when they are needed instead of storing them in memory. I have tried writing a custom "coeff" function for this, and I want to replace the product operator. Right now the wrapper supposedly behaves like an identity matrix.

The code below works as long as I don't use the BiCGSTAB algorithm. However, I am running into the error "static assertion failed: THIS_EXPRESSION_IS_NOT_A_LVALUE__IT_IS_READ_ONLY" when compiling my code seen below when I do try to call the BiCGSTAB algorithm.

Does anyone know what is missing? I do not understand why this matrix would be required as a LVALUE at any point during the algorithm.

Any suggestions on alternative approaches to inverting the matrix are welcome too, I have considered writing my own implementation of the BiCGSTAB algorithm. I was hoping that Eigen would provide a more efficient implementation I could use to avoid having to do my own optimizations.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/IterativeSolvers>

class MyMatrixReplacement;

namespace Eigen {
  namespace internal {
    template<>
    struct traits<MyMatrixReplacement>
    {
      typedef Eigen::Dense StorageKind;
      typedef Eigen::MatrixXpr XprKind;
      typedef double Scalar;
      typedef double RealScalar;
      typedef int StorageIndex;
      typedef Eigen::Index Index;
      enum { 
        Flags = 0,
        RowsAtCompileTime = Eigen::Dynamic,
        ColsAtCompileTime = Eigen::Dynamic,
        MaxRowsAtCompileTime = Eigen::Dynamic,
        MaxColsAtCompileTime = Eigen::Dynamic,
        IsVectorAtCompileTime = false,
        Alignment = 1,
        outer_stride_at_compile_time = Eigen::Dynamic,
        inner_stride_at_compile_time = Eigen::Dynamic
      };
    };
  }
}


class MyMatrixReplacement : public Eigen::MatrixBase<MyMatrixReplacement>
{
public:
  MyMatrixReplacement(){}
  MyMatrixReplacement(int x, int y){}

  typedef typename Eigen::internal::ref_selector<MyMatrixReplacement>::type Nested; 

  Index rows() const {return Index(4);};
  Index cols() const {return Index(4);};
 
  template<typename Rhs>
  Eigen::Product<MyMatrixReplacement,Rhs,Eigen::AliasFreeProduct> operator*(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Rhs>& x) const {
    return Eigen::Product<MyMatrixReplacement,Rhs,Eigen::AliasFreeProduct>(*this, x.derived());
  }

  double* data(){
        return NULL;
      }

  int innerStride(){return 0;}
  int outerStride(){return 0;}

  MyMatrixReplacement &operator=(const MyMatrixReplacement& rhs){return *this;}

  MyMatrixReplacement(const MyMatrixReplacement &rhs){}

  ~MyMatrixReplacement(){ }
};

namespace Eigen {
  namespace internal {
    template<>
    struct evaluator<MyMatrixReplacement>
      : evaluator_base<MyMatrixReplacement>
    {
      typedef MyMatrixReplacement XprType;
      typedef typename XprType::CoeffReturnType CoeffReturnType;
      enum { 
        CoeffReadCost = 1,
        Flags = 1
      };
      
      evaluator(const MyMatrixReplacement& x)
      {}

      CoeffReturnType coeff(Index row, Index col) const
      {
        double entry = 0;
        if(row == col){
          entry = 1;
        }
        return entry;
      }

    };
  }
}


namespace Eigen {
namespace internal {
 
  template<>
  struct generic_product_impl<MyMatrixReplacement, Eigen::VectorXd> // GEMV stands for matrix-vector
  : generic_product_impl_base<MyMatrixReplacement,Eigen::VectorXd,generic_product_impl<MyMatrixReplacement,Eigen::VectorXd> >
  {
    typedef typename Product<MyMatrixReplacement,Eigen::VectorXd>::Scalar Scalar;
 
    template<typename Dest>
    static void scaleAndAddTo(Dest& dst, const MyMatrixReplacement& lhs, const Eigen::VectorXd& rhs, const Scalar& alpha)
    {
      assert(alpha==Scalar(1) && "scaling is not implemented");
      EIGEN_ONLY_USED_FOR_DEBUG(alpha);
      dst = rhs;
    }
  };
 
}
}


int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXd vec(4);
  vec << 1, 2, 4, 8;
  MyMatrixReplacement mat;
  std::cout << mat << std::endl;
  Eigen::VectorXd x(4);
  Eigen::VectorXd vec2(4);
  vec2 = mat*vec;
  std::cout << vec2 << std::endl;
  MyMatrixReplacement mat2;
  mat = mat2;
  
  //Without the part below this code compiles, runs, and does what it should do.
  {
    Eigen::BiCGSTAB<MyMatrixReplacement, Eigen::IdentityPreconditioner> bicg;
    bicg.compute(mat);
    x = bicg.solve(vec);
    std::cout << "BiCGSTAB: #iterations: " << bicg.iterations() << ", estimated error: " << bicg.error() << std::endl;
  }
  
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: It works, if you actually follow the example: https://godbolt.org/z/6d31Mscxe (e.g., don't inherit from `MatrixBase<...>` and don't try to implement `struct evaluator<MyMatrixReplacement>`)

Comment: Thanks, it works and seems to do what I need!